# How to listen to the microphone in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio, audio-recording, microphone

I wonder if there is a way to capture the sound from the microphone with MATLAB, simply process it (I just need a few standard audio features, I can do this myself) and make a decision based on the features. Probably my only feature will be the amplitude of the sound, and I want to make a decision based on that. All I need is a way to capture the live audio, and I can do the rest.

How can live audio be captured (on-the-run, or by saving as small blocks and processing with a small amount of delay) with MATLAB?

I found this [code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18596-real-time-microphone-and-camera-data-acquisition-and-audio-video-processing?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) but I'm getting the error :

```
Error using analoginput (line 46)
The DAQ Legacy Interface is not supported on this platform..
```

Any solution that works under 64-bit Windows 8?

### Note

I asked the question for MATLAB, but at this point, I'm OK with any kind of solution :) What I want as a pseudo-code is as follows:

```
float threshold;
float max_duration;
while (!interrupted) && (timer() < max_duration)
    a = record_audio() // or record_audio(5s)
    b = analyze_audio(a)
    if b.mean_amplitude > threshold
        do(something);
    end
end
```

I'm not sure about the recording process (is it parallel or not) but it doesn't matter. Some live data could be missed during the analysis, it's acceptable for me.

### Edit

Thanks for the help. As the documentation suggests, I ran `daq.getVendors()` and got this output:

```
ans = 
Data acquisition vendor 'National Instruments':
      ID: 'ni'
      FullName: 'National Instruments'
      % ..
```

So I tried `s = daq.createSession('ni')` and I got this error:

```
The vendor 'ni' is not known. Use 'daq.getVendors()' for a list of vendors.
```

Any kind of programming language or external software recommendation to do this is welcome and acceptable :)

Thanks,

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/record-and-play-audio.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure to go to the microphone settings (input settings) and check the "listen to this microphone" checkbox. You should be hear your microphone input from your speakers because the following code will record computer's sound output. Since we are outputting your mic, you will be recording mic.

Then you can record the sound output as:

```
ai=analoginput('winsound');
addchannel(ai,1);
start(ai);
data=getdata(ai);
```

you can listen to it by

```
sound(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error while using `analoginput()`. Also I don't understand how to periodically (online) process the data. This looks like offline, i.e. it records the audio for a while and then stops. What I want is, record the audio and analyze it every `N` (~5) seconds. Is it possible?